# Cannot use Windows authenticator in SQL statement in a form in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I tried to connect my windows user with a table in SQL using where as my windows user

`string name = windowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
then I put my SQL query

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand ("Select [EmployeeName] as Name from Employee where ID=" + name)
```

After this I just want to show in my label the name associate to the ID (which is the windows user)

```
using (var registro = comm.ExecuteReader())
{
    While (registro.Read())
    {
        label1.Text = registro["Name"].ToString();
```

When I run the code it shows this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect Syntax near ''.'

and I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection.  It would solve your problem, too.

Comment: a) Are you really using the Windows name as your record id? b) given its a string you have to single quote it for use in a query. c) As already stated using parameters solves all this for you and makes your code more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass in the name as a parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

```cs
var comm = new SqlCommand("Select [EmployeeName] as Name from Employee where ID=@ID;");

comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
comm.Parameters["@ID"].Value = name;
```

This will likely solve any issues with possible SQL injection and passing in name as a string (surrounded with `'` and with any special characters escaped).

Comment: We hardly need yet another answer saying the same thing. VTC as a duplicate.

Comment: Since I'm new using c#, is hard for me understand everything, also thank you, but now something is wrong this is my code:
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
conexion.Open();
string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
var comm = new SqlCommand("Select [Employee Name] as Name from AlteryxDB.dbo.t_tcnb_employee_loc where ID=@ID;");
comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
comm.Parameters["@ID"].Value = name;
using (SqlDataReader registro = comm.ExecuteReader())
while (registro.Read())
label1.Text = registro["Name"].ToString()